# XML Tree traversal in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am traversing an XML file in Python like this:

```
for node in rootNode1.iter():
    print node.tag
```

My output is:

```
Student
Int_Class_ID
Name
StudentID
EmailID
Address
Int_Class_ID
Street
City
PostalCode
Seminar
Int_Class_ID
SeminarNumber
Course
```

Now I want to save only names which are just above `Int_Class_ID` like this:

```
Student
Address
Seminar
```

Can some one help?

My XML file is like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ModelDiff>
  <Student>
    <Int_Class_ID>1</Int_Class_ID>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <StudentID>1</StudentID>
    <EmailID>br</EmailID>
    <Address>
      <Int_Class_ID>3</Int_Class_ID>
      <Street>c</Street>
      <City>P</City>
      <PostalCode>d</PostalCode>
    </Address>
    <Seminar>
      <Int_Class_ID>4</Int_Class_ID>
      <SeminarNumber>e</SeminarNumber>
      <Course type="f">
        <Int_Class_ID>11</Int_Class_ID>
        <TopicName>g</TopicName>
        <Day>Monday</Day>
        <Date>15/04/2013</Date>
      </Course>
  </Student>
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample XML file?

Comment: Without seeing your code and your XML file, there isn't really much to help you with.

Comment: Can you post your exact xml file.

Comment: This is my exact XML file @kvivek

Answer (score 0):

using `xml.etree` !

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Print children of root with

```
>>> for child in root:
...   print child.tag, child.attrib
```

With this input xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

command gives

```
>>> for child in root:
...   print child.tag, child.attrib
...
country {'name': 'Liechtenstein'}
country {'name': 'Singapore'}
country {'name': 'Panama'}
```